# How can I upload any file to server using alamofire in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am new in swift and I am not able to upload any file. I am able to upload only Image file

my code is like this

```
// import Alamofire
func uploadWithAlamofire() {
  let image = UIImage(named: "bodrum")!

  // define parameters
  let parameters = [
    "hometown": "Pune",
    "living": "Pune",
    "bill":PDFfile, 
  ]

  Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
      multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    }

    for (key, value) in parameters {
      multipartFormData.append((value?.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
    }}, to: "upload_url", method: .post, headers: nil,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
          switch encodingResult {
          case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.response { [weak self] response in
              guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
              }
              debugPrint(response)
            }
          case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("error:\(encodingError)")
          }
  })
}
```

I want to upload any format not just image in PDFfile.

Comment: which format you want to upload? audio file video file ?

Comment: @DhavalRaval .pdf, .jpg , .xls any document format

Comment: Okay buddy look at the answer i added..

Comment: How can I send PDF file in bill parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the format whatever you want to add like this :

**Pdf** :

```
multipartFormData.append(pdfData, withName: "pdfDocuments", fileName: namePDF, mimeType:"application/pdf")
```

**xls** :

```
 let filePath = direcoryUrl.path+"/app.xls"

    var bytes = [UInt8]()

    if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) {

        var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: data.length)
        data.getBytes(&buffer, length: data.length)
        bytes = buffer
    }


    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: {
        multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(Data(fromArray: bytes), withName: "app",fileName: "app.xls", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")
    }
```

Comment: @DhvalRaval What is pdfData did I need to convert url to data?

Comment: @DhvalRaval How can I send PDF file in bill parameters?

Comment: @Mujtaba you have to do same thing which you have done with image in question for pdf.. you have to covert pdf file to data and send it to server same as image using the format i have shown in my answer

Comment: @DhvalRaval It getting crash -[__NSCFNumber dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde02b5d82f46f96c'

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492386/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-alamofi) for error